# finding two pages similarity

Tags: php, artificial-intelligence, web-scraping

I develop a project were in certain spot, some one share a news and to confirm this news another user have to attach the same news from another source so the original news score increase as a trusted news.

what is the solution for comparing two pages and find the similarity probability between both of them?

I code in PHP so any solution compatible with this lang is highly appreciated.

i read that Neural networks are very heavy and performance costing so i need some kind of lightweight solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can

http://php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php

or

use any comparing software (there are really a lot of them out there) and use them in terminal so you can process it in php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: Hi MC-fish,i need an algorithm so i can find the % of similarity not the exact text string ones.

Comment: the first method has a 3rd param, exactly for that:)